# Como incluir no Python uma função feita em C?

Tags: c, python, python-3.x

Quero usar uma função feita em `C`.

Exemplo:

Tenho uma função

```
int swap(){ 
    printf("lista");
}
```

E quero chamá-la pelo Python...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você vai ter que fazer é gerar uma biblioteca dinâmica com o seu código C. No Linux isso significa uma bilioteca ".so" e no windows seria uma ".dll"

Assumindo que você esteja no Linux e o nome do seu arquivo C é "hello.c", o gcc pode gerar essa biblioteca dinâmica através dos [seguinte comando](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14884126/90511):

```
gcc -shared -o libhello.so -fPIC hello.c
```

Agora, pra chamar essa biblioteca do Python você pode usar a biblioteca [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), que é parte da biblioteca padrão do Python:

```
import ctypes

libhello = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./libhello.so")
libhello.swap()
```

Para exemplos mais avançados, em que a função recebe ou retorna parâmetros, você vai precisar converter os dados do formato Python para o formato C. Consulte a documentação do ctypes para os detalhes.